# Angular 14 serve from different folder, cannot match any route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular14

I am serving my angular application at path **domain.com/app1/**

I want the browser to show url as following: *domain.com/app1/page1* or *domain.com/app1/page2*

My angular.json has `"baseHref": "/app1/"`
and App module has `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '.' }`

and App routing has

```
[
  {
    path: 'app1',
    redirectTo: 'page1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'page1',
    component: OneComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'page2',
    component: TwoComponent
  }
]
```

It is working perfectly if i visit the **domain.com/app1**, angular will redirect to **domain.com/app1/page1**

However if i reload or try to visit **domain.com/app1/page1** directly then i am getting `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'app1/page1'`

I cannot find anything in documentation. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
[
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'page1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'page1',
    component: OneComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'page2',
    component: TwoComponent
  }
]
```

And in your index.html `<base href="/app1">`.
Just with this should work.

In the other hand, if you want to use the DI `APP_BASE_HREF` apprach you could put this in your AppModule:

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/app1'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`page1` and `page2` needs to be children of `app1`, like this:

```
            [
          {
            path: 'app1',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            children: [
             {
            path: 'page1',
            component: OneComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'page2',
            component: TwoComponent
          },
          {
            path: '', 
            redirectTo: 'page1'
          }
        ]
          },
        ]
```

Comment: I haven't tried this method. maybe it'll work but it's better to change ```basehref``` at one place only.  so going with @cybering solution.